# Object Timer not working correctly (pause button, play button)

Tags: javascript, oop, object, timer

I'm trying to set an object Timer. Actually, when I click on the play button, all it works correctly.

But when I'm trying to pause, (in console.log), my timer return -1 (-2, -3, etc.) on each click.

How do I prevent this?

```
class Timer{

    constructor(times){
        this.time = times;
        this.buttonPlay = document.getElementById('play')
        this.buttonPause = document.getElementById('pause')
        this.buttonStop = document.getElementById('stop')
        this.displayTimer = document.getElementById('timer')
    }

    decrementTime(){
        t.buttonPlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
            let checked = 0
            let s = setInterval(()=>{
                console.log(t.time[checked]--)
                if(t.time[checked]<0){
                    checked++;
                    console.log('checked = '+ checked)
                    if(checked === 3){
                        clearInterval(s)
                    }
                }
            }, 1000)
            t.buttonPause.addEventListener('click', function(){
                clearInterval(s);
            })
        })
    }
}

let t = new Timer([4, 7, 8]);
t.decrementTime()
```

Comment: what function are you trying to achieve passing in a list of integers to the `Timer` class ?

Comment: [4,7,8] are intergers that i want to decrement to 0. One by one. Its actually working, but when i'm clicking on pause, i get -1 on each click. I don't know really why

Comment: What's your expected console output?

Comment: When i'm click on pause, timer pause. After that, i play again and my timer continue. 
Actually if i'm click on pause i got -1, i don't know why i got this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-1" you are getting, are because every time you click play your program starts checking from the first element.

To avoid that, simply move the `let checked = 0` outside the event listener:

```js
class Timer {

    constructor(times) {
        this.time = times;
        this.buttonPlay = document.getElementById('play')
        this.buttonPause = document.getElementById('pause')
        this.buttonStop = document.getElementById('stop') //does nothing on this script
        this.displayTimer = document.getElementById('timer') //does nothing on this script
    }

    decrementTime() {
        let checked = 0
        t.buttonPlay.addEventListener('click', function () {
            let s = setInterval(() => {
                console.log(t.time[checked]--)
                if (t.time[checked] < 0) {
                    checked++;
                    console.log('checked = ' + checked)
                    if (checked === t.time.length) {
                        clearInterval(s)
                    }
                }
            }, 500)
            t.buttonPause.addEventListener('click', function () {
                clearInterval(s);
            })
        })
    }
}

let t = new Timer([4, 7, 8,50]);
t.decrementTime()
```

```html
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">pause</button>
<button id="stop" disabled>stop</button>
<button id="timer" disabled>timer</button>
```

**EDIT:** I also changed the stop condition to be able to process arrays of any lenght and added a bigger one just for testing

Comment: Oh yeah ! Thank you dude :)